# Can someone explain what the output of fft means in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft

```
>> fft([1 4 66])

ans =

  71.0000           -34.0000 +53.6936i -34.0000 -53.6936i
```

Can someone explain according the result above?

Comment: People could answer your question better if you could be more specific.  What about this do you not understand?

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT** Well that's embarassing.  I left out a factor of 2.  Updated answer follows...

The Discrete Fourier Transform, which an FFT algorithm computes quickly, assumes the input data of length `N` is one period of a periodic signal.  The period is `2*pi rad`.  The frequency of the output points is given by `2*n*pi/N rad/sec`, where `n` is the index from `0` to `N-1`.

For your example, then, `71` is the value at `0 rad/sec`, commonly called `DC`, `-34+53.7i` is the value at `2*pi/3 rad/sec`, and its conjugate is the value at `4*pi/3 rad/sec`.  Note that by periodicity, `2*pi/3 rad/sec = -2*pi/3 rad/sec = 4*pi/3 rad/sec`.  So the second half of the spectrum can be regarded as the frequencies from `-pi..0` or `pi..2*pi`.

If the data represents sampled data at a constant sampling rate, and you know that sampling rate, you can convert `rad/sec` to `Hz`.  Let the sampling rate be `deltaT`.  Its reciprocal is the sampling frequency `Fs`.  Then the period is `T = N*deltaT sec = 2*pi rad`.  `1/T` gives the frequency resolution `deltaF = Fs/N Hz`.  Therefore the frequency of the output points is `n*Fs/N Hz`.

Comment: The frequency of the output points should be `2 * n*pi/N rad/sec` according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform , right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a vector of [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) representing your signal in frequency domain.

Comment: Which frequencies does it represent?