# What's the frequency range for a FFT?

Tags: range, transform, fft, frequency

So, as far as I have read up, for a signal with data points 0...n, I get a result from 0 to n, but I can omit n/2...n. Correct ? So now I have n/2 data points. How is the relation between the frequency range of these data points to the signal data ? E.g. what frequency is n/2 (0 is 0 hz I guess) ?

Comment: this question may be more appropriate for http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should be on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573702/units-of-frequency-when-using-fft-in-numpy/8574113#8574113 or last paragraph of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658659/can-someone-explain-what-the-output-of-fft-means-in-matlab/2660304#2660304

Answer (score 3):

An FFT by itself has no frequency range.  It could be anything.

The frequency range of an FFT result depends on the sample rate frequency at which the input data points were evenly sampled.  The FFT results are then data points in the frequency domain spaced at the sample rate frequency divided by the FFT length, from 0 or DC up to half the sample rate.

Comment: Hm, that's what I expected, but my results somehow seem to correlate to sample rate frequency / FFT length (half of the input length) divided by 2. Am I correct to assume that a sinus wave signal with a wavelength of 1 (1 Hz) and an amplitude of 1 should produce a bump in the FFT at 1 Hz with a magnitude of 1 ? Because for me with the above formula the bump is a 2 Hz and the magnitude is off the charts  (in fact it seems to correlate to the data point count, I have 256 data points and an amplitude of 64 in the FFT data).

Comment: When I mix two sin waves, their relative amplitudes and positions on the FFT graph are correct though...

Answer (score 1):

Xk, the FFT coefficient with index k corresponds to the frequency k·fs/N.

You don't have to do the math, you can use [fftfreq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) function. If your spectrum is 0-centered, you can center the frequencies as well with [fftshift](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html).

```
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(10, 0.1)
>>> array([ 0.,  1.,  2., ..., -3., -2., -1.])

np.fft.fftshift(freqs)
>>> array([-5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

---

To understand the answer it's good to remember:

1. [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) is an algorithm to calculate a [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT), which itself is a sampling of the [discrete-time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) (DTFT).
2. DFT can sample the DTFT for any frequency, but the FFT implementation limits the number of frequencies to the number of samples provided (N), this is for efficiency purpose.
3. FFT also limits the sampling to the interval 0 (DC offset) to 2 times the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency). Any other frequency sampled would be a copy of of one already in the FFT interval, as DFT is periodic.
4. Nyquist frequency is half the sampling rate fs, as stated in the [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).
5. Each [coefficient](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70394/dft-coefficients-meaning) of the spectrum is denoted Xk, k being an integer between 0 and N-1 (or equivalently, due to periodicity, an integer within -N/2 and (N-1)/2, see note below). The coefficient is both an amplitude and a phase angle to be associated with a sinusoid of some frequency, but neither the sinusoid nor the frequency are part of the coefficient..

That in mind, we have this relationship:

- The interval goes from f=0 for k=0 to f=fs for k=N (excluded). The extent is fs.
- This interval is divided into N bins.

Thus Xk, the coefficient with index k corresponds to the frequency k·fs/N. This frequency can be positive or negative (when k is negative, using periodicity property).

If you look carefully you'll see neither DFT nor FFT actually manipulate absolute frequencies in Hz, they use indices k spanning a range, and assign N to the [normalized frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_frequency_(signal_processing)) 1 (often noted 2π, the equivalence in radians).

The normalized frequency is the unit-less quantity f/fs (or 2π·f/fs when expressed in radians), but DFT/FFT don't care, all they know is this is the normalized frequency 1 and there are N frequencies sampled, they ignore fs and work in the interval -0.5 to +0.5 normalized frequency.

**Note:** FFT functions in Numpy or Scipy return coefficients for indices `0` to `(N-1)//2` first, then coefficients for `(-(N-1))//2` to `-1` (positive frequencies first, negative frequencies last). You can swap the two portions to have frequencies in increasing order (using [fftshift](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html)). The reason of this order is FFT actually computes the DFT for k=0 to k=N-1. So half the spectrum (with normalized frequencies 0.5 to 1) is outside the Nyquist interval and these frequencies are actually copies of the frequencies at normalized frequencies f-1 (-0.5 to 0), which are negative. Taking advantage of this periodicity, `fftfreq` returns negative frequencies for the upper half of the spectrum.

The user of DFT/FFT has the burden to do the math involving fs when required, but often it is not required before the final step, because the user is generally more interested in the normalized frequency than in the Hz for all intermediate calculations and plotting. E.g.

[image: plot of the FFT of a sine wave, the x axis shows normalized frequencies]
([image source](https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2020/01/how-to-plot-fft-in-python-fft-of-basic-signals-sine-and-cosine-waves/))

When it's time to assign an actual frequency in Hz, the sampling frequency is either used or chosen. For example if you synthesize a signal from its manually-constructed spectrum, using the inverse DFT, the sample sequence has no particular frequency, it's only when we associate the samples with a sampling frequency that they represent some frequency, the one you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the generic FFT normally used in programming is 0-22.05khz for a 44.1 sample and 0-24khz for a 48khz input.

Actually, the raw output of the FFT is reflected over zero, so -22.05 to + 22.05, and most programs use the 0-22.05 half only...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeaJq.png